# Do not replicate items if they exists in a foreach loop

Tags: array, php

My head is clearly not working here. The logic is simple but I can't seem to get it right.

I have a tv schedule post type and I want to display:

`2016-12-01
2017-04-01
2017-05-17`

Instead of: 
`2016-12-01
2017-03-01
2017-03-01
2017-03-01
2017-03-01
2017-03-01`

At the moment I am stuck with repeating times. I want to only show one time if it already exists as in the first case.

This is my code:

```
`<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tv-schedule',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'future'),
);
$posts_array = query_posts($args); 

foreach ($posts_array as $post_array) {
    $date = $post_array->post_date_gmt;
    $new_date = date ('Y-m-01', strtotime($date) );
    echo $new_date . '<br />';

    /*
    if(!in_array($new_date, $post_array->post_date_gmt)){
        //$a[]=$value;
        echo "test";
    }
    */

}`
```

Comment: I put this in there for the next interesting thing which is a filter - you can only filter by month and year.... so that is why there is ` $new_date = date ('Y-m-01', strtotime($date) );`

Comment: Wasn't sure why your php code had backticks around it, but I removed them in my answer below so the syntax highlighting would work. Feel free to add them back in before you use the code though if you needed them for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it right... I knew my big head was not working:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tv-schedule',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'future'),
);
$posts_array = query_posts($args); 

$lastdate = "";         

foreach ($posts_array as $post_array) {

    $date = $post_array->post_date_gmt;
    $new_date = date ('Y-m-01', strtotime($date) );

    if ($newdate != $lastdate) {
        echo $newdate;
    }

    $lastdate = $newdate;

}
?>
```

Comment: Actually my code should still do the trick, just needed to use != operator instead of the !== operator it appears. Try it out and see if you don't mind, I'd like to know if I'm missing something else, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just set a flag to check for a new value, and only display the date if the new value does not match the flag, like so:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tv-schedule',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'future'),
);
$posts_array = query_posts($args); 

$flag = ''; // set an initial value that won't match the first date

foreach ($posts_array as $post_array) {
    $date = $post_array->post_date_gmt;
    $new_date = date ('Y-m-01', strtotime($date) );
    if($new_date != $flag) {
        echo $new_date . '<br />';
        $flag = $new_date; // $flag only changes when we actually display a new date
    }

    /*
    if(!in_array($new_date, $post_array->post_date_gmt)){
        //$a[]=$value;
        echo "test";
    }
    */

}
```

**UPDATE**

Changed !== to != so that it would work.

Comment: Thank you @industrial-themes... The loop with a set flag only give me the first available date. Is there something I am missing?